# Scalar function in U-SQL?

Tags: u-sql

Can we call azure data lake analytics database's table value functions from c# code behind in U-SQL script? Any operation that can be done on Azure data lake analytics database would be fine.

Thanks

Comment: No you can't do that.   Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Agreed with wBob. Can you provide more details what you try to accomplish? TVFs are U-SQL and cannot be called from within C# code. You can call C# code from within U-SQL.